# HTML form password requirements

Tags: html, forms

I need to create a registration form in HTML which has a password input with the following constraints:

***Is a mandatory field, should be validated. Minimum of 7 characters. Should have at least one special character and one number. Do not use java script, use HTML 5 features.***

I have written the following code to for the above input:

```
<input type="text" name="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\W_]).{7,}" required>
```

I need to submit this code as part of an assignment and I get the error:

***Correct HTML Component with the name 'password' must be used with appropriate constraints***

which means I am not using the correct attributs.

What changes should I make to the pattern attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works perfectly with validation message

```
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="pw" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\W_]).{7,}" title="Minimum of 7 characters. Should have at least one special character and one number."></p>
```

try it here :
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern3

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work.

`Password:<input type="password" name="pw" pattern="^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{7,}$" title="Minimum of 7 characters. Should have at least one special character and one number and one UpperCase Letter.">`

Pattern attribute will also use a Regular Expression to validate your form-data.So for more results you can also search for [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)